# How to count number of dates per month from the records in custom text file?

Tags: java

I have a text file which having the records as in the below format,

```
03-Jan-2018 2   1   12  N   MT680N  617 U Cecil
```

I need to count the dates per month and print as follows,

```
Jan Feb ...
5    2  ...
```

I've tried as follows but couldn't get the expected result, your guidance is highly appreciated.

Current code looks like this:

```
public static void displaySummaryofContracts()
{   
    int numberOf3N4Lines = 0;      
    int totalLines = 0;
    String filePath = "test.txt";
    String arr[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    String space = "   ";

    ArrayList<String> numberOf3N4s= new ArrayList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))){
        String lineText = null;

        while ((lineText = bufr.readLine()) != null){  
            String[] col = lineText.split("\t");
            if(col[2].equals("3") || col[2].equals("4")){
                numberOf3N4s.add(lineText);
                numberOf3N4Lines++;
            }
            totalLines++;
        }
    }  

    catch (IOException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ioex){
        System.err.println(ioex); 
    }

    System.out.println("Total Number of Lines: " + totalLines);
    System.out.println("Total Number of Lines equivalent to 3 and 4: " + numberOf3N4s);
    System.out.println("Number of dates connected to each month:");
    System.out.println(arr[0] + space + arr[1] + space + arr[2] + space + arr[3] + space + arr[4] + space + arr[5] +
               space + arr[6] + space + arr[7] + space + arr[8] + space + arr[9] + space + arr[10] + space + arr[11]);
}
```

Ignore the following line, which is used to skip a record based on the predefined value in a column.

```
if(col[2].equals("3") || col[2].equals("4"))
```

Comment: Add each one in your loop into an array, and print it the same way you print `arr[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Create another array when you declare your `arr[]` so you can save the information there, and output it later at the same time as `arr[]`. *(Also, if you don't know the exact size it will have, just use a List)*

So the result would be something along the lines of

```
String arr[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
String secondArray[] = new String[12];
String space = "   ";
```

Here you do your operations and add them to the array

```
String result = xxx
arr[0] = result;
```

And to output them at the end of all you just show first the array `arr[]` which contains the headers, and later the second array which contains the results

```
for(String s : arr) {
  System.out.print(s + " ");
}

System.out.println();

for(String s : secondArray) {
  System.out.print(s + " ");
}
```

This will print

```
Jan Feb Mar [...]
10 14 11 [...]
```

For the print to work you must use print(), not print**ln**(). Also if you want it to be good formatted you may use [printf](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Summer16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf) instead of print(). With it you can do so it looks like

```
Jan Feb Mar [...]
10  14  11  [...]
```

Comment: What is the String result = xxx?

Comment: @Dave That's meant so you put there your operations. The ones which will grant you the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a object Month with the variables name and counter.
Set the name in the constructor:

```
public string name;
public int counter;
public Month(string name){this.name = name;counter = 0;}
```

And create a method in your main class:

```
public void addMonth(String month) {
Month m = new Month(month);
    monthList.add(m);
}
```

Then create a global array of objects like:

```
List<Month> monthList = new ArrayList<Month>();
```

Then in your main:

```
 String arr[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

for(String s: arr)
{ 
    addMonth(s);
}
```

What is left is to check if the month(the month you got from your text file line) is equal to the month.name

```
for(Mont m: monthList)
{ 
if(month == m.name)
{
m.counter++;
} 
}
```

If you want to output it

```
for(Month m: monthList){System.out.print(m.name+space);}
System.out.print("\n");
for(Month m: monthList){System.out.print(m.counter+space);}
```

Exact spacing I don't known but I think you can figure that out.